# t-stat for difference in means (from Mostly Harmless Econometrics)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

How do you compute a $t$-statistic for the null hypothesis that the difference in means is zero for this information?

```
Group        N         Mean      Std. Error
================================================
Hospital      7,774    3.21      0.014
No hospital  90,049    3.93      0.003
```

This is perhaps the first calculation in *Mostly Harmless Econometrics* by Angrist and Pischke, found in section 2.1 "The Selection Problem" (p. 13).

The difference in means is (obviously) 0.72 and the $t$-statistic should be 58.9. But despite my best attempts and I can't see how they get that number. I would have guessed that it should be $$t = \frac{0.72 - 0}{\sqrt{0.014^2 + 0.003^2}} \approx 50.3,$$ but apparently that is not the case.

How should it really be done? Or is it just a typo?

Comment: Depending on the t statistic I use, I get either 50.3 or 65.4 :/

Comment: what are the standard deviations for these groups?

Comment: @rmrouse88 I think that they ought to be 0.014*7774^.5 and 0.003*90049^.5

Comment: @VincentGuillemot It could of course just be a typo...

Comment: Thanks.  I also get 50.3 using the assumption of unpooled variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are the last data set [here](https://economics.mit.edu/people/faculty/josh-angrist/mhe-data-archive), and the analysis is an equal-variance t-test after dropping the missing values (7 or 9 in both variables) and recoding the health status variable from 1=Excellent to 5=Excellent.

Your calculation for the denominator would be correct with an unequal-variance t-test.  For an equal-variance t-test you need the pooled variance.
That's noticeably different in this example because the variances are quite different in the two groups and the groups are of very different size.

The problem with **that** calculation is rounding error: the standard errors have been rounded to 3dp, which is only 1 significant figure for one of them.
With the real data, the two standard errors are 0.003347249 and 0.01423366, so the rounding to 1 significant figure reduced the larger group's SE by about 10%.

With the full data, the equal-variance $t$-statistic is 58.912 and the unequal-variance $t$-statistic is 48.894, both on more degrees of freedom than are worth worrying about.

The moral of the story is that tables with an appropriate number of digits for someone to *read* don't have enough precision to replicate the analysis exactly. That's fine; you just need to not expect to replicate the analysis exactly. For that, you need the original data or more precision.   The table as printed is fine for getting a sense of the difference between the groups and how it compares to the uncertainty: the practical implications of a $t$-statistic of 48 or 58 or 60 are the same.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT USE THE DATA IN THE TABLE OF PAGE 13. USE THE ORIGINAL DATASET AND DOFILE TO CALCULATE.
HERE IS THE WEBSITE:

https://economics.mit.edu/people/faculty/josh-angrist/mhe-data-archive